# JQueri как сделать добавление строки без дублирования

Tags: jquery

Приветствую! У меня вопрос пожалуйста посоветуйте или помогите решить возможно легкий вопрос:

Мало что знаю о JQ нашел вот такой код:

$(".add").click(function() {
    $("form > p:first-child").clone(true).insertBefore("form > p:last-child");
    return false;
});

$(".remove").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});

при нажатии добавить, добавляет новую строку как надо, но копирует все введенные данные в предыдущих полях input
Как сделать так что бы добавлял ту же структуру но только пустые поля для ввода новых параметров?

Надеюсь смог объяснить вопрос!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так попробовать:

```
$(".add").click(function() {
    var _this = $("form > p:first-child").clone(true);
    _this.find('input').each(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });

    _this.insertBefore("form > p:last-child"); 
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: Да теперь работает как надо благодарю! А еще не подскажите!? мне нужен будет какой то обработчик данных который будет сохранять полученные данные в файл как база данных, где его искать? это готовое решение или его нужно создавать специально?

Comment: Примите ответ тогда уж :) А то администрация ругаться будет)

Чтобы в БД сохранить, надо написать обработчик на стороне сервера. Это несложно)